# Custom entry in Windows Explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-11, navigation

Does anybody know, how to create new entry in explorer navigation pane, just below new Home entry?

I already wrote a code which can create custom entry, and already tried setting different **SortOrderIndex** values, but with no luck - I only achieved moving custom entry above Home
which is not what I want.

```
:: Settings
SET CLSID={CUSTOM_CLSID}
SET ICON=%%USERPROFILE%%\Pictures\Icons\googledrive.ico,0
SET NAME=Google Drive
SET /A ORDER=65
SET STORAGE=%%USERPROFILE%%\Google Drive

:: Create Explorer entry
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%NAME%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%" /v "System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%ORDER%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\InProcServer32" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%SYSTEMROOT%%\system32\shell32.dll" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "FolderValueFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d "40" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "4034920525" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%NAME%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%" /v "System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%ORDER%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\InProcServer32" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%SYSTEMROOT%%\system32\shell32.dll" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "FolderValueFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d "40" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "4034920525" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\DefaultIcon" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%ICON%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\Instance" /v "CLSID" /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "17" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\DefaultIcon" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%ICON%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\Instance" /v "CLSID" /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "17" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "TargetFolderPath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%STORAGE%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "TargetFolderPath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%STORAGE%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v "%CLSID%" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\%CLSID%" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%NAME%" /f
```

---

Expected result
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some research I found a way to achieve what I want.

Default **SortOrderIndex** value for **Home** entry is 64. Next entry is a default **OneDrive** (018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6) with index 66. Setting **SortOrderIndex** for our custom entry to 64, pushed it to the top of the first Navigation pane section with **Home** entry, while setting it bigger like 65, moved it to the last section with **This PC** entry.

[Custom entry with SortOrderIndex set to 64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvDBt.png) 
[Custom entry with SortOrderIndex bigger then 64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XojQm.png)

I don't know why OneDrive with index 66 is still in the top section below Home entry, while anything custom is send to the last section, but I managed to resolve that problem, by setting **SortOrderIndex** for our **Home** (f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903) entry to lower value (i.e. 50), which was done by making a key in HKCU with correct CLSID:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%QUICK_ACCESS_ORDER%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%QUICK_ACCESS_ORDER%" /f >NUL 2>&1
```

After that, we have additional 14 slots for new entries in first section, starting from 51 to 64.

---

Here is a script which will create new navigation pane entry below **Home** entry.

To customize it, change variables placed in `:Custom entry settings` section. Also, don't forget to generate unique CLSID for new entry.
You can copy this file, change CLSID again and repeat whole process for multiple custom entries.

Launching script second time with same settings will delete custom entry, see `:ELEMENT_EXISTS` section.

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Checking for administrator rights using fsutil which will only work if under 
:: admin rights which just queries the volume here %systemdrive% 
:: for a 'dirty bit' for corrupted volume 
:: WITHOUT TOUCHING ANY FILES/REGISTERY ANYTHING at all
:: source >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295806

:: Using an elevated runas cmd prompt/powershell is deliberately avoided 
:: for security/privacy reasons and to have a SYSTEM-LESS way
FSUTIL dirty QUERY %systemdrive% >NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 GOTO NO_ADMIN_ERROR

:: Custom entry settings
SET ENTRY_CLSID={018D5C66-1111-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE5}
SET ENTRY_ICON=%%USERPROFILE%%\Pictures\Icons\googledrive.ico,0
SET ENTRY_NAME=Google Drive
SET ENTRY_ORDER=64
SET ENTRY_TARGET=%%USERPROFILE%%\Insync\xxx@gmail.com\Google Drive

:: QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID :: Home entry CLSID - shouldn't be changed
:: QUICK_ACCESS_ORDER :: Home entry order position - this will allow us to set custom entry below `Home` entry
:: 
:: This will also change Home entry sort order - to restore default value (64), delete following keys from registry:
:: HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%
:: HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%
:: --- YES, delete this keys completly as they are custom created by this script
SET QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID={f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903}
SET QUICK_ACCESS_ORDER=50

:: Check if CLSID already exists
REG QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID% >NUL 2>&1 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 GOTO CREATE_ELEMENT
GOTO ELEMENT_EXISTS

:: Create Explorer entry
:CREATE_ELEMENT
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%ENTRY_NAME%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /v "IsCustom" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%ENTRY_ORDER%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /v "System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\DefaultIcon" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%ENTRY_ICON%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\InProcServer32" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%SYSTEMROOT%%\system32\shell32.dll" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\Instance" /v "CLSID" /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "17" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "TargetFolderPath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%ENTRY_TARGET%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "4034920525" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "FolderValueFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d "40" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%QUICK_ACCESS_ORDER%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%ENTRY_NAME%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /v "IsCustom" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%ENTRY_ORDER%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /v "System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\DefaultIcon" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%ENTRY_ICON%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\InProcServer32" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%SYSTEMROOT%%\system32\shell32.dll" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\Instance" /v "CLSID" /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "17" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\Instance\InitPropertyBag" /v "TargetFolderPath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%ENTRY_TARGET%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "Attributes" /t REG_DWORD /d "4034920525" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%\ShellFolder" /v "FolderValueFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d "40" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%QUICK_ACCESS_CLSID%" /v "SortOrderIndex" /t REG_DWORD /d "%QUICK_ACCESS_ORDER%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%ENTRY_NAME%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v "%ENTRY_CLSID%" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f >NUL 2>&1
ECHO Entry created successfully.
GOTO :EOF

:: Check if CLSID points to custom created entry
:ELEMENT_EXISTS
REG QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID% /v IsCustom >NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO DELETE_ELEMENT
ECHO [ERROR] CLSID %ENTRY_CLSID% already exists.
ECHO Change it and try again.
GOTO :EOF

:: Delete Explorer entry
:DELETE_ELEMENT
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\%ENTRY_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v "%ENTRY_CLSID%" /f >NUL 2>&1
ECHO Entry deleted successfully.
GOTO :EOF

:: Error message for reference
:NO_ADMIN_ERROR
ECHO [ERROR] This script needs to be executed as an administrator.
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

---

And here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCm8r.png)

Comment: So, what was the "secret" to placing the custom folder in the desired position.

Comment: Added additional explanation at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still on 10, haven't upgraded to 11 yet, but I play a lot with **Explorer** customization/automation so this is good to know. As an aside, why dod you opt for `.bat` over **PowerShell**?  Familiarity? If you'd like to see a **PowerShell** version of your code, I'd be happy to post.

Comment: --- answering almost 1 year later :) ---
Yep, I'm more familiar with writing scripts for Linux environment than Windows - that's why I wrote this one in Batch. Sadly, I've never found enough time to learn PowerShell. If you're still interested in making a PowerShell version, I'd love to make your answer accepted.